# Problem aligning binary and hexadecimal numbers in siunitx table

Tags: tables, siunitx

Could you tell me what's wrong with next code? I want to get a three columns tabular where numbers are typeset with `typewriter` family and centred below its header. Numbers won't have any decimal part, they are integers and their decimal, binary and hexadecimal representation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{math-rm=\mathtt, 
        group-digits=false, 
        table-figures-decimal=0, 
        table-number-alignment=center,
        input-digits={0123456789ABCDEF}
        }

\begin{tabular}{SS[minimum-integer-digits=8]S}
\toprule
{Decimal} & {Binary} & {Hexadecimal} \\
\midrule
63 & 00111111 & 3F \\
250 & 11111010 & FA \\
117 & 01110101 & 75 \\
220 & 11011100 & DC \\
171 & 10101011 & AB \\
94 & 01011110 & 5E \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, second column doesn't have enough space and second and third column are not correctly aligned. What am I misunderstanding in `siunitx` guide?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The binary numbers in the second column are centered with `table-format=8.0`. Also the overfull `\hbox` warnings are gone:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{math-rm=\mathtt,
        group-digits=false,
        table-figures-decimal=0,
        table-number-alignment=center,
        input-digits={0123456789ABCDEF}
        }

\begin{tabular}{SS[minimum-integer-digits=8,table-format=8.0]S[table-format=2.0]}
\toprule
{Decimal} & {Binary} & {Hexadecimal} \\
\midrule
63 & 00111111 & 3F \\
250 & 11111010 & FA \\
117 & 01110101 & 75 \\
220 & 11011100 & DC \\
171 & 10101011 & AB \\
94 & 01011110 & 5E \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you. I thought that `table-figures-decimal=0` was enough. It looks like I also need to specify `table-format`. But why first column was well aligned without any other information?

Comment: @Ignasi: I think the default setting of `table-figures-integer=3` is the reason that the first column is already centered.