# Display hexcode in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, siunitx

I want to display some hexcode aligned in a table. This is what I got:

[image: messed up table]

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Dirty table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}|p{6cm}}
\textcolor{red}{0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 3162 0005 0009 0000 1000 0000 0900 0000 0000 0000} 0014 0000 0000 0000 0000 usw.
&
\textcolor{red}{0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 3162 0005 0009 0000 1000 0000 0900 0000 0000 0000} 001a 0000 0000 0000 0000 usw.
 \end{tabular}
\label{tab:BitcoinCoreMobileSignatur}
\end{table}
```

How to align this hex blocks correctly? I tried siuntix Package with

```
\begin{tabular}{S[table-column-width=6cm]|S[table-column-width=6cm]}
```

with some more variations found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164706/problem-aligning-binary-and-hexadecimal-numbers-in-siunitx-table). You have some ideas?

Thanks

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  the problem is that the widths of the letters aren't uniform.  for that, you'd ideally use a monospace font, but you most likely don't want the usual "typewriter" font.  perhaps someone knows of a more appropriate one.

Comment: you didn't get that image from that input I assume, the code for the image would have been a better test the posted code exactly aligns already as all the digits, and `a` have the same width in computer modern.

Comment: @ david I exaclty get this image from this code. but anyways, thank you and with egreg answer now its fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a monospaced font. Here it is with Inconsolata:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{xcolor,array}

\newlength{\hexcodewidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Dirty table}\label{tab:BitcoinCoreMobileSignatur}

\medskip

\ttfamily
\settowidth{\hexcodewidth}{0}% width of a character
\setlength{\hexcodewidth}{\dimexpr24\hexcodewidth+1em}% 24 characters per line
\setlength{\spaceskip}{\dimexpr1em/5}% five spaces

\begin{tabular}{p{\hexcodewidth}|p{\hexcodewidth}}
\textcolor{red}{%
  0000  0000  0001 0000  0000  0000
  3162  0005  0009 0000  1000  0000
  0900  0000  0000 0000} 0014  0000
  0000  0000  0000 usw.
&
\textcolor{red}{%
  0000  0000  0001  0000  0000  0000
  3162  0005  0009  0000  1000  0000
  0900  0000  0000  0000} 001a  0000
  0000 0000 0000 usw.
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a monospace font, or use a normal font but set each hex digit in a fixed width box.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,array}
\settowidth{\dimen0}{1}
\def\z#1{\zz#1 !!!!}
\def\zz#1#2#3#4{%
\ifx!#1\unskip\else
\makebox[\dimen0]{#1}%
\makebox[\dimen0]{#2}%
\makebox[\dimen0]{#3}%
\makebox[\dimen0]{#4}%
\space
\expandafter\zz
\fi}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p}

\addtolength\textwidth{40pt}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{P{6cm}|P{6cm}}
\textcolor{red}{0000 00ag 0001 0eef 0000 0000 3162 0005 0009 0000 1000 0000 0900 0000 0000 0000} 0014 0000 0000 0000 0000 usw.
&
\textcolor{red}{ccf0  fff1 0000 0000 0000 3162 0005 0009 0000 1000 0000 0900 0000 0000 0000} 001a 0000 0000 0000 0000 usw.
 \end{tabular}

\bigskip

{\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}{P{6cm}|P{6cm}}
\textcolor{red}{0000 00ag 0001 0eef 0000 0000 3162 0005 0009 0000 1000 0000 0900 0000 0000 0000} 0014 0000 0000 0000 0000 usw.
&
\textcolor{red}{ccf0  fff1 0000 0000 0000 3162 0005 0009 0000 1000 0000 0900 0000 0000 0000} 001a 0000 0000 0000 0000 usw.
 \end{tabular}}


\bigskip


\begin{tabular}{P{6cm}|P{6cm}}
\textcolor{red}{\z{0000 00ag 0001 0eef 0000 0000 3162 0005 0009 0000 1000 0000 0900 0000 0000 0000}}
\z{0014 0000 0000 0000 0000 usw.}
&
\textcolor{red}{\z{ccf0  fff1 0000 0000 0000 3162 0005 0009 0000 1000 0000 0900 0000 0000 0000}}
\z{001a 0000 0000 0000 0000 usw.}
 \end{tabular}




\end{document}
```